# Help starting up multiple Dropbox instances on Ubuntu startup

Tags: startup, dropbox

I tried following these instructions here http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Multiple_Instances_On_Unix but my 2nd instance wouldn't start up on boot. I tried the rc.local method with a bash script but even running the bash script itself from the command line wouldn't start the 2nd instance.

The only command that has worked to start the 2nd instance for me is here:
HOME=$HOME/.dropbox-alt /usr/bin/dropbox start -i

How can I get it to just start on boot? I'm a bit of a linux newbie so need a little hand-holding, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I think Dropbox has killed this possibility. "Fix an issue that allowed multiple Dropboxes to run on Linux" - https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes. Bad news!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found a solution but here is what worked for me...

From Dash (top left corner of screen, Ubuntu icon) open `gedit` (Text Editor) and type:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOME=$HOME/.dropbox-alt /usr/bin/dropbox start
```

Now save this as `DropboxAltStarter.sh` in your Home directory (`/home/Username/`)
Open the terminal `CTRL + ALT + T` and type:

```
chmod 755 ~/DropboxAltStarter.sh
```

This command will make the file executable.

Now type in Dash `Startup Applications` open it and then press `Add`

Name: `Dropbox2` (or something)

Command: `/home/Username/DropboxAltStarter.sh`

Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. It still works. Changed the icons at :

```
.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.0.3/images/hicolor/16x16/status/
```

inside the pseudo-home to visually differentiate the tray icons.